# Maven dependency of type/classifier bin not showing up in runtime classpath

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, classpath

I have a project that is using an artifact that I've uploaded into a local Maven repo with the type and classifier bin.  I want to rely on this artifact at runtime, and want to reference the file via the classpath.

As a point of reference, my project defines a dependency such as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.site</groupId>
  <artifactId>binary-dependency</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>bin</type>
  <classifier>bin</classifier>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn dependency:build-classpath`, I can see the artifact listed.  However, in my code, calling `System.println("java.class.path")` does not include this, both in Eclipse using m2e and via Maven on the command line.

Any idea why this won't show up in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Is it jar? Then type should be jar.

And if it's not jar, how do you expect it to be added to classpath?

Comment: No, it's actually an executable that I want to use.  In this instance, it's the chromedriver binary that Selenium 2 relies on (I left this out to keep things general).  My thought was that since I can make sure it gets pulled down to the filesystem as a dependency, that I could find its location via the classpath system property and tell Selenium 2 to look for it there.

Comment: To clarify (didn't realize hitting enter would submit), I was thinking that it would just be a clever way to get an absolute path to a runtime dependency of the app via a Maven dependency.  If it won't be added to the classpath variable due to the fact that it's not a jar, then I'll figure out another way.  I think my confusion was more that Maven will tell you that it is part of the classpath via the dependency plugin, however the file won't appear on the classpath at execution time.

Comment: Well, you can download this dependency using Maven, but where to store it and how to use it later, is really up to you. It cannot be added to classpath though. If you want it in classpath, you can wrap it in jar (after all jar is just an archive).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I did try wrapping it in a jar and that failed to, even though I didn't want to go that route since it meant extracting the jar.  I wound up going for a solution of packaging the artifact as a resource and writing it out to Maven's project build directory instead.